# WPF Cyclic Converter

Tags: wpf, converters

When you drag the slider, you get a ConvertBack (expected), but why do I then get a "Convert" straight after that? I'd only expect Convert to be called when its first initialized, or if it was raising a property change notification, but it doesn't.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Slider Value="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={l:Converter}}"/>
</Window>


public class Converter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely occurring because you're using .NET 4, which changed the way bindings work a little bit : http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/

Whereas prior to 4 the binding wouldn't update back (assuming that it didn't need to), the new behavior is to do that by default.  Rationale is explained in the linked blog.

Edit: I suppose I should ask if there is a reason you don't want it to convert back, or if it's just curiosity?  If you need to prevent converting back, the clearest strategy is probably to keep track of your last converted value to parrot back :

```
public class Converter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return this;
}

public object lastValue;

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return lastValue;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    lastValue = value;
    return value;
}
}
```

There's also the option of setting the binding to OneWayToSource, which would keep it from setting back to the slider value... assuming you don't need to push data back to the slider.

Comment: This cropped up in building code written in 3.5 in 4.5. In a few cases the value being passed into Convert/ConvertBack isn't exactly the same (for example precision loss in number types) and its causing odd behavior. It would be nice if you could opt out of the new behaviour.

Comment: That's somewhat surprising, I wouldn't expect the behavior to be goofy - do you mean that precision is strange with floats/doubles?  It's normal for a float/double to be 1.5 one way and 1.499999999 the other, that's one reason to avoid using them unless you really mean to.  If that's the case, have you considered using decimal instead?

Comment: For the time being I'm just caching the "value" in ConvertBack, similar to your suggestion. Decimal is another option, but would break a lot of existing code, so the caching hack will do for now.

Comment: We use a bunch of floats internally, which are a huge pain in my rear when performing geometry calculations.  I'd recommend writing a method like this:

    `private const float EPSILON = 0.0001f;
    private bool NearlyEqual(float leftValue, float rightValue, float epsilon = EPSILON)
    {
      return Maths.Abs(leftValue - rightValue) < epsilon;
    }`

Make sure to tune epsilon to a value that captures the inaccuracy in your calculations, it can usually be much smaller than my example.